# How does one transform the real lattice to the reciprocal lattice in a 3D crystal?

Tags: fourier-transform, diffraction, crystals, x-rays

I'm working of understanding the math behind relationship between real space and reciprocal space in relation to X-ray diffraction. I understand that in X-ray diffraction the crystal lattice can be view as a wave. My question is how does one transform the real lattice to the reciprocal lattice in a 3D crystal?

Comment: Take the Fourier transform.